# Flatten nested named value pair in Boost Serialization

Tags: c++, inheritance, serialization, boost, base-class

The canonical way to serialize in Boost.Serialization it to define a `serialize` (or `load`/`save`) function that translate the value-state of the object into a series of more primitive values. If the serialization archive need named value pairs this also requires to define names.

For example

```
struct A{
   double x; int y; unsigned z;
   template<class Ar>
   void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned){
     ar 
        & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(x) 
        & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(y) 
        & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(z)
     ;
   }
}
...
A a;
boost::archive::xml_oarchive xoa{ofs};
xoa << BOOST_SERIALIZATION(a);
```

Which generates a structure similar to:

```xml
<a>
  <x>1.2</x>
  <y>2</y>
  <z>3</z>
</a>
```

However this syntax induces a hierarchy, that sometimes is not desired, for example when using (plain) inheritance, to extend a class.

```
struct B{
   double x; int y;
   template<class Ar>
   void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned){
     ar 
        & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(x) 
        & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(y) 
     ;
   }
};
struct C : B{
   unsigned z;
   template<class Ar>
   void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned){
     B& B_part = (*this);
     ar 
        & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(B_part) // uses code from base
        & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(z) 
     ;
   }
};
...
C c; c.x = 1.2; c.y = 2; c.z = 3;
boost::archive::xml_oarchive xoa{ofs};
xoa << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(c);
```

```xml
<c>
  <B_part>
     <x>1.2</x>
     <y>2</y>
  </B_part>
  <z>3</z>
</a>
```

**This is somewhat artificial. Is there way to force the archive to flatten this refepresentation?** and get this instead:

```xml
<c>
  <x>1.2</x>
  <y>2</y>
  <z>3</z>
</a>
```

Of course I could rewrite the structure as

```
struct C : B{
   unsigned z;
   template<class Ar>
   void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned){
     ar 
        & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(x)
        & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(y)
        & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(z) 
     ;
   }
};
```

But then this becomes cumbersome because I have to repeat all the code from the base class in the derived class.

For example, a hypothetical code could be like this:

```
   void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned){
     B& B_part = (*this);
     ar 
        & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_UNNAMED(B_part) // uses code (and names) from base, does not create a new level
        & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(z) 
     ;
   }
```

**Is this serialization of base class, without generating a lower level, something contemplated in the library?**

I know that Boost.Serialization still does the serialization job, however the XML can become more readable in this way.

Boost.Serialization has a lot of documentation on serializing base and derived classes (for classic polymorphic inheritance) (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#base) but it doesn't seem to have documentation for this use of inheritance classes for aggregation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way, (I don't know if it works only by chance).

```
struct C : B{
   unsigned z;
   template<class Ar>
   void serialize(Ar& ar, unsigned u){
     B::serialize(ar, u); // base class serialization
      // or boost::serialization::serialize(ar, static_cast<B&>(*this), u);
     ar 
        & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(y)
        & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(z) 
     ;
   }
};
```

(I rejected this solution earlier because I thought it would generate a duplicated XML header because it seems to nest an archive inside another, but it doesn't.)

This will flatten any other structure into the archive, not only a base class. Moreover, `boost::serialization::serialize` doesn't work with primitive types by design so you never end up with with an "unnamed" leaf node.

This generates the desired structure and reusing the code from the base:

```
<c>
  <x>1.2</x>
  <y>2</y>
  <z>3</z>
</c>
```

---

**Note:** this is exactly what the manual says **not** to do when serializing a derived class, https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#base

> Resist the temptation to just cast `*this` to the base class. This might seem to work but may fail to invoke code necessary for proper serialization.

But I think he is referring to (de)serializing *polymorphically*, saving from an instance of derived and loading an instance in the base (pointer).

This use would never work here anyway because deserializing into a `C` **value** something serialized from a `B` **value**, or the other way arround will be a logical error within value-semantics philosophy (and a runtime error since they have a different number of members).

Answer (score 2):

> Resist the temptation to just cast *this to the base class. This might seem to work but may fail to invoke code necessary for proper serialization.

You're right that it's not strictly necessary if the base class isn't polymorphic. It's a recommendation. But I stand by this recommendation.  It's better to have a simple rule than to have to re-think every instance.

I question the value of trying to "shape" the xml file to some particular taste and/or exterior requirements.  This couples the C++ data structures to fulfill some other role.  If you really need to make the xml files "readable" or whatever, a much better method would be to use some other tool such as xslt to modify/filter the xml generated by the serialization library.  This would effectively permit you to make the best C++ data structure for the program while preserving the convenience of processing the xml.

Comment: Thank you Robert. Your recommendation is well taken.  I think this is not a problem of boost serialization. It is just rather that it got caught in the clash of two worlds, the value semantics world and the polymorphic reference/pointer world. In my view value types are (must be) naturally serializable (in fact Sean Parent adds it as a requirement).Polymorphic types are never value types in my opinion, unless they are wrapped in a concept-based value semantics. So heroic attempts to produce value semantics from polymorphic types is full of pitfalls unfortunately even using your great library.

Comment: Also, it is not just a matter of readability. The problem is conceptual, a derived class is an extension of the base class, there is not even a good name to tag the base part. Also it is about having the option not to repeat the serialization code of the base class. (Of course I am not talking about polymorphic inheritance here.)